# incompatibility between tikzposter class and microtype package

Tags: microtype, tikzposter

I've just started using the new `tikzposter` class (having previously used the `fancytikzposter` package from the same author) and immediately discovered that using the `microtype` package causes TeX to fail.

I'm wondering whether anybody else has come across this as I'm not sure what to do.  My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
%\block{\textls{title}}{text}
\end{document}
```

The commented out line in the middle is one of the reasons for using `microtype`, i.e. to get more control over letter spacing.  I get the same in `pdftex`, `xetex` and `lualatex` and I'm using a freshly updated TeXlive installation.

The failing error is:

```
! Missing endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   protect
l.5 \end{document}

?
```

Comment: This is most certainly a bug.

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug to me as well—any clues as to where to start looking?  Having it fail at the `\end{document}` doesn't provide many clues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a rather tricky one ... I would contend it's a bug in `tikzposter`.

The problem is that `tikzposter` uses `\AtBeginDocument` for starting a `tikzpicture` environment, which is then closed `\AtEndDocument`. This means that any other code that a package (in this case `microtype`) inserts `AtBeginDocument` is executed inside a group, hence any local assignments will become undone `AtEndDocument`. Specifically, `microtype` disables some commands that are only allowed inside the preamble `ABD`, which triggers the error `AED`.

The `clsguide` advises:

> The `\AtBeginDocument` hook should not be used for code that does any
>   typesetting since the typeset result would be unpredictable.

Even though the actual typesetting that `tikzposter` does is not the real problem here but rather the group that it opens, I would still say that this qualifies as improper use of `\AtBeginDocument`. `tikzposter` could instead use the `\AfterEndPreamble` command from `etoolbox` (which it loads anyway).

Comment: well spotted!  thanks for pointing out those hooks, I'll have to remember them for my next debugging excursions…  I'll report the bug to the class authors with a patch

Comment: For reference, the necessary (one-line) patch to `tikzposter.cls` is described [here](https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/issues/12/bug-in-use-of-atbegindocument), but not yet in CTAN.