# Comparison: umbcposter vs baposter vs tikzposter

Tags: posters, tikzposter, baposter

For a scientific conference I would like to make a poster. I have noticed that there are three more or less popular classes for that: umbcposter, baposter, tikzposter.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the classes compared with each other?

**Edit:** I am not talking about just a list of LaTeX packages with which one can make posters. I am looking for **advantages and disadvantages** (as already mentioned). This is **not provided** by [How to create posters using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex)

Comment: I think you'll find the answer in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-to-create-posters-using-latex

Comment: No, I don't. I found lists and tutorials but no comparison via advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Posters are big things with quite a few (but important) information. That leads to one conclusion: Place stuff by hand. All automated placement needs fixing either way. Choosing a class/package really is a matter of taste. It doesn't matter, if you generate boxes with TikZ, `tcb` or `pstricks`.

Comment: Voting to reopen because this isn't a duplicate. Even if comparing the options is hard/opinion-based (as I think @Johannes_B is insinuating), this should not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Place stuff by hand = use PowerPoint? Or choose package... which one is providing what you are saying? It may be that its a matter of taste, but I can't have taste about something that I haven't tried yet, and for now I wanted to draw on the knowledge of the community instead of trying out every available class (which is what stackexchange is about, I guess). **advantages/disadvantages are not about opinion**.

Comment: What i was trying to say: There are (in my pov) no advantages or disadvantages of one class/package over another. You as the document author are responsible that it looks nice. Everybody may choose their weapons based on own skills.

Comment: There is no advantage/disadvantage since you just need to put things on a pdf page with a subjective judgement. Our other comparison questions are about functionalities and package conflicts, say, subfig vs. subcaption etc. For posters as lons as you can place things down they work.

Comment: These are advantages and disadvantages: Conflicting with other packages are concrete disadvantages. Features that are supported by classes are advantages. I'll give examples for what I already found out in an own answer and hope others will add their findings.

Comment: You also forget beamerposter and tcolorbox

Comment: @skan: Please feel free to edit information into my answer below, if you have any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Please feel to correct or add aspects!*

## tikzposter

#### Advantages / Pros

1. Recently worked on - last time in 2015 (in CTAN is a 2014 version so far)
2. Supports block columns
3. Supports "notes" to blocks

#### Disadvantages / Cons

1. Conflicts with package hyperref* (= fixed bug, but fix is not yet in CTAN)
2. Package ragged2e shifts the title in unexpected way*.
3. Conflicts with package microtype*  (= fixed bug, but fix is not yet in CTAN
4. No free floating blocks supported

|* Own experience

#### Tips

For package `xcolor` use `\PassOptionsToPackage` to pass options to xcolor. Wether you also `\usepackage{xcolor}` or not makes no difference since tikz already loads `xcolor`. Because of this options may clash if they are passed directly to a `\usepackage{xcolor}`. An example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table}{xcolor}
```

## baposter

#### Advantages / Pros

1. Got a lot of praise

#### Disadvantages / Cons

1. Not included in CTAN (but can be rather easily downloaded and included).
2. Not recently worked on - last time in 2011
3. I had trouble getting it to work.

## a0poster

#### Advantages / Pros

1. Feature: Supports large canvases
2. Provides appropriate font sizes from /tiny (12pt) over \normalsize (24.88pt) to \VERYHuge (107pt)
3. Support from A0 to A3

#### Disadvantages / Cons

1. Does not support any ways of setting blocks
2. Does not support the change of the definition of \normalsize

## beamerposter

#### Advantages / Pros

?

#### Disadvantages / Cons

?

## tcolorbox

#### Advantages / Pros

?

#### Disadvantages / Cons

?

Comment: Can you give references for your points? I know for sure that tikzposter is *not* conflicting with `xcolor` in any way.

Comment: By the way, `tikposter` has been last worked on in 2015, but the changes did not made their way to CTAN so far. https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter

Comment: TikZ poster is based on TikZ which uses xcolor as its main color provider. There cannot be a clash whatsoever. You probably used `dvipsnames`  or similar keys for the package which is not defaulted with TikZ. For that add `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before `\documentclass`. Also they definitely don't clash with `hyperref` or `microtype` they must be user errors but not package errors. `ragged2e` is not even a measure for judging any package. It has a very specific task which is not necessarily meant to support every package out there. These are pretty questionable conclusions.

Comment: ragged2e: I am using ragged2e a lot. When reading it's purpose at http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/ms/ragged2e.pdf it does not sound very special to me.

Comment: `hyperref`: When I add hyperref (without any options) I get the error message "Can only be used in preamble. \HyperFirstAtBeginDocument"

Comment: `xcolor`: True enough: I put all my options into \PassOptionsToPackage` and it works fine.

Comment: `microtype`: Error messages are (no options): "Missing endcsname inserted \end{document}" and "Can be used only in preamble \end{document}". Of course I load `microtype` and `hyperref` in the preamble.

Comment: The conflict with `microtype` is a bug. (See, e.g., [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/165846/32888).) It was fixed in [`d870a6a`](https://bitbucket.org/surmann/tikzposter/commits/7acf067088cb7efa117e758335f148537321f416), but this hasn't made its way to CTAN yet, it seems. The problem with `hyperref` and `tikzposter` is effectively the same bug as with `microtype` and `tikzposter`.

Comment: Until it is in CTAN, it should be considered a disadvantage, because users will use the CTAN version. However, I'd like to add help: How does one get the newest version of tikzposter into ones repository?

Comment: user49283: You can use the `@` symbol to ping me. I only saw this because I happened to check back. To answer your question, though, see [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/32888). Note that putting this in a local texmf tree means that it will *always* take precedence over the version in your TeX distribution, at least until you remove it from the local texmf tree. Also, how is getting a lot of praise an advantage/pro? I agree with @percusse that a lot of these conclusions seem questionable.

Comment: @Adam Liter: The same way that one looks at the number of like a product at Amazon gets considered when buying a product. That would be a Pro. It's not scientific, but pragmatic.

Comment: You could ping the maintainer of `tikzposter` and ask him to push a new version to CTAN.

Comment: A bad way of selecting a product on Amazon is no better as a way of selecting software. According to your summary, it gets a lot of praise but you had trouble getting it to even work. Does the praise outweigh the non-workingness? Presumably not. And 'I had trouble getting it to work' could mean anything - it isn't a disadvantage without more detail. (Maybe you had trouble getting it to work because your computer blew up or your cat kept walking over your keyboard during testing.)

Comment: Can you please add your document that leads to these errors? I cannot replicate any of your errors with your description. Also I used these before a lot and neever happened to me either. And again having a specific bug is not an advantage/disadvantage. I can fill the page with baposter bugs. Also where is this praise you are mentioning. I actually seearched and found nothing. And you are missing `beamerposter`

Comment: @percusse: Feel free to add to my post. Btw I am using tikzposter by now.